# Can two 3-dimensional vectors spans a $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have done some similar questions, for example the following:

> Verify if three 3-dimensional vectors (v1:[...],v2:[...],v3:[...]) will span $\mathbb{R}^3$.

All I have to do is to put three vectors into a 3 by 3 matrix and perform elementary row operations, and to check if there are 3 pivots.

However, this makes me think if I have two 3-dimensional vectors and it does have a reduced row-echelon form with 2 pivots. Can I say that they span $\mathbb{R}^2$

More generally, does the dimension of vectors limit the space that the set of these vectors can span? (Ex: Can three 4-dimensional vectors span $\mathbb{R}^3$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence after the colon is incomplete.  However, if I get what you're driving at, the answer is yes that $k$ vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ will, if they are independent, span a $k$-dimensional subspace.

Recall that the number of vectors in a basis is an invariant; and that this number is called the dimension.

Moreover, any two $k$-dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic.  So if we have $k$ linearly independent vectors, they span a space *isomorphic to* $\Bbb R^k$.

Answer (score 1):

The things that you mentione are false, The problem is your definition of basis.

Let a finite vectorial space $V$ over some field $\mathbb{K}$, a subset $\mathcal{B}=\lbrace v_1,v_2, \cdots v_n\rbrace \subset V$ is a basis for $V$ if for every $v\in V$ then $v$ is linear combination of the elements  of  $\mathcal{B}$(it is $v=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_jv_j $ for $\alpha_j\in \mathbb{K}) $ and if $\mathcal{B}$ is a set linearly independent(it means if $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_j v_j=0$ then should occur that $\alpha_j=0 \forall j$.
If the set $\mathcal{B}$ is finite we say that $V$ have a finite basis and the number of elements of $B$(unique) the dimention of $V$

Now in the particular case of $\mathbb{R^n}$ if you have a set of vectors $\mathcal{B}=\lbrace (1,0,0, \cdots 0),(0,1,0, \cdots, 0)\rbrace$ then $\mathcal{B}$ spann a subespace of $\mathbb{R^n}$ in particular spann vectors of the form $(x,0,0, \cdots,0)+(0,y,0, \dots,0) :x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ which in any case spann $\mathbb{R^{2}}$.

Comment: oh okay thanks. I just start learning Linear Algebra, so my definitions might not be so concrete as I am also trying to understand all these definitions and theorems

Comment: Great, I edit my answer to get more exact and carefuly

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to the title of your question is no, two vectors, independent of the number of dimensions they have, can only generate at most, a 2d space.

This is because you need at least as many vectors as dimensions for the generated space.

If you have only one vector, you can spawn a line, in any higher dimensional space, you can have a 6d vector, but because is only one, it can only generate a line, 1d space, which is the set of all linear combinations of it.

The dimensionality of your generator vectors only describe their geometry in the containing, source space, but in the inner space generated by their linear combinations, you will have as many dimensions as independently linear vectors, as they can't be linearly represented by each other, and thus spawn an internal space taking each vector as a coordinate axis (just a way of seeing it), and this space is isomorphic to $R^n$.

Imagine the columns of your matrix as vectors in space, and maybe you can see more easily the relationship between the source space (normally $R^n$) and the target space.

Comment: Oh your comment actually made me realize that i have made a mistake in my title. I suppose to say if they can span $\mathbb{R}^2$. The answer I suppose is Yes? (As explained in previous answers)

Comment: @YanZhuang yes!, thats correct!